# Make dynamic Angular components

Tags: angular

I am creating an Angular 7 app.
In this app I am using contenteditable div and in this div, I want to add a component when do a new paragraph. I am able to insert the code for the component but it is not initializing/working.

```
formatParagraph(event) {
    if (event.charCode === 13) {
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
      document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<app-block-add></app-block-add>');
    }
  }
```

However if I add the  to the contenteditable div manually (and not dynamically) it initializes/works.

```
<div contenteditable="true" (keypress)="formatParagraph($event)">
  <p><app-block-add></app-block-add></p>
</div>
```

How can I make Angular "start" the `<app-block-add>` when dynamically added?
There are no errors and the  code is added to the div but not started.

Comment: refer https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: I didn't get your problem.. can you elaborate more. Or if possible can you  produce stackblitz